# Why nginx adds %5C before domain?

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, server, subdomain

I am building app using Django, recently I needed to implement subdomains for multitenant databases, where I use subdomain as tenant identifier.

When I deploy application on server instead of http://test1.example.com I get this url in the debugger http://%5Ctest1.example.com

Same happens even if I don't request subdomain, i.e. I enter http://example.com, but debugger says the requested url is http://%5Cexample.com

Because I use subdomain as identifier this forces me to add %5C(i.e. backslash) to my matches table. Really not a problem, but it is ugly.

Why does this happen? Is it nginx fault or something else?

I use [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) if it matters, but I doubt it can affect the request url, it just gets subdomain name from it.

My nginx configuration(I use it with gunicorn):

```
upstream example.com {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/home/webapps/bhc_virtualenv/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream test1.example.com {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/home/webapps/bhc_virtualenv/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream test2.example.com {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/home/webapps/bhc_virtualenv/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name example.com test1.example.com test2.example.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/webapps/bhc_virtualenv/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/webapps/bhc_virtualenv/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /home/webapps/bhc_virtualenv/bhc1/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /home/webapps/bhc_virtualenv/bhc1/media/;
    }

    location / {
        # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
        #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
        # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
        # can be set properly within the Rack application
        proxy_set_header Host \$http_host;

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
        # Comet/long-poll stuff.  It's also safe to set if you're
        # using only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx.
        # Otherwise you _want_ nginx to buffer responses to slow
        # clients, really.
        # proxy_buffering off;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f \$request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://example.com;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/webapps/bhc_virtualenv/bhc1/static/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%5C` is backslash `\` url encoded. In your nginx configuration file, you do not need to escape the `$` symbol.

```
# remove the backslash
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

You'll want to remove all the backslashes in your configuration where you are attempting to escape `$`. With your current configuration, nginx is passing HTTP headers with backslash prepended to Django, which is causing the URL you see in your debugger.